# issue connecting RestSharp POST request to web API with ASP.NET Core MVC controller

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, timeout, restsharp

I have a ASP.NET core MVC controller in VS2017 and 
I'm trying to make a rest request in the following manner:

```
        var baseURL = @"http://localhost:44317/";
        var client = new RestClient(baseURL);

        var request = new RestRequest(@"api/values", Method.POST);
        request.AddJsonBody(new Scan
        {
            sid = scanId.ToString(), scanPath = scansParentPath

        });            
        var response = client.Execute(request);
```

and the receiving class is:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] Scan value)
    {
    }
}
}
```

and the response i get is a timeout exception. 
What can be the reason for this exception? Am I implementing the rest call in an incorrect way?

Answer (score 0):

Your RestSharp POST request works on my side . The first step is to confirm that remote server post action works as expect , try to use Fiddler or Postman to do the post request and debug the web api to confirm that .

Or you can try to extend the timeout of request :

```
request.Timeout = 300000;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the connection was marked as SSL. Once I removed the checkbox of EnableSSL all worked fine.